# READING A FILE (FORTRAN)

Tags: arrays, formatting, fortran, fortran90

I have a file with real numbers. In each row of the file there are 10 real numbers and then 10 such rows. I want to read the file along the row and store the numbers in a 1-dimensional array with 100 entries. So I want to read along a row and save the numbers in an array 'a' such that the numbers in the first row are stored in the array elements a(1) to a(10) and then a(11) to a(20) should be the numbers in the second row and so on. How can this be done in FORTRAN?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. Surely there are some fossils on this site that remember FORTRAN.

Comment: @nicomp Fossils? There are 2,5k followers of [tag:fortran].

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a fossil. I first did Fortran 50 years ago and still remember a lot of it in spite of having gone through phases of C, C++, Java, VBA, SQL (if that counts as a language) and innumerable assemblers, scripting languages and shells.

Here are some ways of reading numbers from a file. If an unformatted read runs out of numbers, it just goes to the next line.

```
    integer i,j
    real*8 realArray(100)
c       read data 10 items per row
    open(unit=1,file='input.txt')   
    do 10 i=1,10
    read(1,100) (realArray((i-1)*10+j),j=1,10)
10  continue
c   read(1,100) realArray
c   read(1,*) realArray
    write(6,*) ((realArray((i-1)*10+j),j=1,10),i=1,10)
    write(6,100) realArray
    write(6,*) realArray
100 format(10F10.0)
    close('input.txt')
    stop
    end
```

So the first two ways would not report an error if (say) one of the lines only contained 9 numbers but the third one would.